# Jquery UI implementation

Tags: plugins, jquery-ui

I have to register the jQuery UI in function file. I don't want it directly in header.php

```
function my_jquery_ui() {
// register your script location, dependencies and version
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-1.8.16', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.16');
// enqueue the script
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-1.8.16');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_ui');
```

According to firebug, the jQuery plugin is registered

I'm trying to create tabs which you can see it here:

http://www.vmjconsulting.com/wordpress01/testing/#tabs-1

Please Advise.

Comment: jQuery-ui is being loaded in the footer below your tabs script tags. You need to set jquery as a dependency for jQuery Ui.  How to enqueue scripts has been [answered numerous times](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=enqueue+scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enqueuing jquery ui tabs as well?

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );`

Then setting the element in your main javascript file?

`jQuery('#tabs').tabs();`

Comment: It worked once you add  jQuery(document).ready(function($){